# how to use top and free to see what is bogging down the system?

Tags: disk-usage, system, pipe, top, free

I wasn't able to grab the output from top, but I had many, many leafnode instances listed.  They weren't using, individually, many resources.  Perhaps in aggregate they were bogging down the system.

Logs of `/var/log/news/news.err` show:

```
Dec 22 01:26:16 doge fetchnews[4121]: Cannot obtain lock file, aborting.
Dec 22 01:28:12 doge leafnode[3950]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:12 doge leafnode[3964]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:12 doge leafnode[3951]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:13 doge leafnode[3976]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:13 doge leafnode[3942]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:13 doge leafnode[3944]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:15 doge leafnode[3977]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:15 doge leafnode[3949]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:15 doge leafnode[3974]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:15 doge leafnode[3965]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:15 doge leafnode[3975]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:15 doge leafnode[3952]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:16 doge leafnode[3945]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:16 doge leafnode[3963]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:17 doge leafnode[3943]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:17 doge leafnode[3966]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:33 doge leafnode[3905]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:33 doge leafnode[3909]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:40 doge leafnode[3904]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:40 doge leafnode[3910]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:43 doge leafnode[3903]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:45 doge leafnode[3879]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:45 doge leafnode[3880]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:45 doge leafnode[3902]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:46 doge leafnode[3908]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:48 doge leafnode[3896]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:48 doge leafnode[3882]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:48 doge leafnode[3895]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:48 doge leafnode[3893]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:48 doge leafnode[3911]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:48 doge leafnode[3881]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
Dec 22 01:28:48 doge leafnode[3894]: Cannot write to client: Broken pipe
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ date
Thu Dec 22 01:36:22 PST 2016
thufir@doge:~$
```

not sure what to make of that.  Is there some way with `top` or `free` to see how to what extent `leafnode`, or `fetchnews` or `texpire`, are using resources?  These three programs are part of the leafnode NNTP lightweight news server.  Shouldn't really be that intensive.

Comment: Broken pipe indicates that the command at the other end terminated before receiving all input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find **htop** more user friendly

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

It will display usage of CPU as well as memory, and you can sort by any of the columns in the display. This can make it easier for you identify which programs/processes that are using your resources.

[image]

**Free -m** displays memory usage in Mibibytes. The column *used* corresponds *approximately* to the values displayed in the head of the htop window (the data used to match better in earlier versions of Ubuntu, before 16.04 LTS).

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           4041         869        1813          33        1358        2728
Swap:         16399           0       16399
```

Comment: Why don't you add the out for `free` also :).